# HTML file to website

Tags: html, joomla

very rookie question here.

I have written an Html file using netbeans. CSS and javascript is used too in the file but it is still just a .html file.

What I want to do is use this file as a page on my website using joomla. Can anyone help me do this?

Do I need to split it up into .css and.php and so on or is there an easier way?

Comment: You'd be better of reading a formal book on Joomla than winging it with trivial stuff like this. I don't use Joomla, but reviews claim this is a good book to read: http://www.amazon.com/Joomla-Explained-Step---Step-Guide/dp/0321703782/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1327269078&sr=1-2

Comment: You need to build a *Joomla Template* if you want a Homepage; you can add any static HTML page into Joomla, but it doesn't work dynamically with Joomla or Joomla extensions.

Answer (score 2):

first of all u have to integrate your template into the joomla template here is link that is helped u how to do this ...

http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/15-3-My-First-Template-P776.html

go to via this tutorial this is easy to understand how to make a joomla template...

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is convert your HTML template to a Joomla template and use it.
Please refer the following tutorial to understand how to do it-
http://www.tobacamp.com/tutorial/5-easy-steps-converting-html-template-to-joomla-template/

Answer (score -1):

You can just FTP it to the server then use a wrapper.

Comment: If it's a `.html` file, and he's worried about "splitting it up" into "...php and so on" this might not work quite as intended.

Comment: but where am I supposed to put it on the server? in the joomla templates or?

Comment: that's what I was thinking David

Comment: He doesn't need to if he just wants to display the HTML page by it's self. He could also use wrapper if FTPd as well.

Comment: You can put it in the root or the page or another place if you desire.